# How do I create an array of struct with strings in c#

Tags: c#, arrays

***Note*** this is for a homework assignment, im not looking for a direct answer but guidance so i can figure this out....

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using static System.Console;
using static System.Convert;

namespace OnYourOwnCalendar
{

struct Appointment
{
    public string title;
    public string description;
    public string date;
    public string startTime;
    public string endTime;
    public string who;
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Appointment app;
        string myTitle;
        string myDescription;
        string myDate;
        string theStartTime;
        string theEndTime;
        string theWho;
        WriteLine("Welcome to your appointment book");
        for (int i = 1; i < 6; i++)
        {

            Write("Please tell me your first appointments title: ");
            myTitle = ReadLine();
            Write("Please tell me a brief description of your appointment: ");
            myDescription = ReadLine();
            Write("Please tell me the date of your appointment: ");
            myDate = ReadLine();
            Write("Please tell me the time of your appointment: ");
            theStartTime = ReadLine();
            Write("Please tell me the time your appointment ends: ");
            theEndTime = ReadLine();
            Write("Please tell me who your appointment is with: ");
            theWho = ReadLine();
            app.title = myTitle;
            app.description = myDescription;
            app.date = myDate;
            app.startTime = theStartTime;
            app.endTime = theEndTime;
            app.who = theWho;
            WriteLine($"Your appointment is:\nTitle:{app.title}\nDescription:{app.description}\nDate:{app.date}\nStart Time:{app.startTime}\nEnding Time:{app.endTime}\nWho is Required:{app.who}");
            Write("================Press Enter to Continue================");
            ReadKey();
        }
        /*foreach (string App in appArray)
        {
            WriteLine($"Your appointment is:\nTitle:{app.title}\nDescription:{app.description}\nDate:{app.date}\nStart Time:{app.startTime}\nEnding Time:{app.endTime}\nWho is Required:{app.who}");
            ReadKey();
            Write("================Press Enter to Continue================")
        }*/
    }
}
```

This code works for all intensive purposes, the problem is I need to create an array of struct and then regurgitate all of the information entered.
When I go to create the array element as the book shows using:

```
Appointment[] app = new Appointment[6];
```

I start getting all kinds of errors, i've tried every possible method I could think of, i've scanned the 1980's stereo manual of a textbook 1000+ times and unfortunately my professor is of no use when it comes to answering questions.
so i think i've seen every error possible, ranging from cant implicitly convert type string[] to string, to does not contain a definition for "" and no accessible extention method blah blah blah... what am I not understanding here? how do I make this work?

Comment: On what line and what error you get? I do not see any real 'error problem' in the code you wrote.

Comment: I removed the code that was causing errors and basically started fresh to see where I was making mistakes. I know it starts when I attempt to make an array from the structure. It completely throws everything out of wack then and I've received multiple errors for the various ways I've tried

Comment: Change `Appointment[] app;` to `Appointment[] app = new Appointment[5];`, and all `app.` to `app[i - 1].` and the code works without problems. _(No error)_. The `i - 1` is because indexing start from `0` and in for you have `i = 1`, change this to `for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)` and you can use `app[i].`.

Comment: That got me to where i needed to be, it through an error during runtime of System.IndexOutOfRangeException: 'Index was outside the bounds of the array.'

Comment: but i can figure that one out from here. Thank you!